# How to call django-taggit tags using templates tags

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-haystack

I want to filter by multiple Django-taggit tags using Django Haystack and Elasticsearch, I have written a facets function in a custom forms but I can't retrieve the results that match with the selected filter(s) in my templates.

So how can I possibly do this?

My models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True, max_length=255, default='')
    description = models.TextField(default='')

    ptags = TaggableManager()

    image = models.ImageField(default='')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def _ptags(self):
        return [t.name for t in self.ptags.all()]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product',
                       kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My custom forms.py:

```
from haystack.forms import FacetedSearchForm

class FacetedProductSearchForm(FacetedSearchForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = dict(kwargs.get("data", []))
        self.ptag = data.get('ptags', [])
        super(FacetedProductSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(FacetedProductSearchForm, self).search()

        if self.ptag:
            query = None
            for ptags in self.ptag:
                if query:
                    query += u' OR '
                else:
                    query = u''
                query += u'"%s"' % sqs.query.clean(ptags)
            sqs = sqs.narrow(u'ptags_exact:%s' % query)

        return sqs
```

Passing forms in Views.py:

```
class FacetedSearchView(BaseFacetedSearchView):

    form_class = FacetedProductSearchForm
    facet_fields = ['ptags']
    template_name = 'search_result.html'
    paginate_by = 6
    context_object_name = 'object_list'
```

If needed, the urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^product/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', ProductView.as_view(), name='product'),
    url(r'^search/', FacetedSearchView.as_view(), name='haystack_search'),

] + static(MEDIA_URL, document_root=MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And finally, in the templates side I have a search_form.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<div class="col-md-6">
    <form class="search-form-container" action="/search/" method="get">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="icon-addon addon-lg">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search for good..." class="form-control" name="q" id="q" autocomplete="off">
                <div id="selction-ajax"></div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="col-md-3">
                <dl>

           <!-- Checkbox is placed below -->

                <div>
                  <input class="facet" id="" type="checkbox" name="ptags" value="Solo" data-toggle="toggle" /> Solo
                </div>

                <div>
                  <input class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right" type="submit" value="apply filter" onclick="return onFacetChangeApplied();" />
                </div>

            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: have you set `faceted=True` for ptags in your search_indexes?

Comment: Yes I just added it, But I still have the same error, no result are showing up

Comment: add your search_indexes

Comment: I made it work thanks! But how can call tags in my search result templates for a given object? I've tried this but didn't work: `<span class="label label-info">{{result.object.ptags.name}}</span>`

Comment: `{% for tag in result.object.ptags.all %}
            <li> {{ tag.name }} </li>
        {% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding `faceted=True` for ptags in your search_indexes, run commands

1. `python manage.py clear_index`
2. `python manage.py update_index`

edit your forms.py

```
         if self.ptag:
            query = None
            for ptags in self.ptag:
                if query:
                    query += u' OR '
                else:
                    query = u''
                    query += u'"%s"' % sqs.query.clean(ptags)
                    sqs = sqs.narrow(u'ptags_exact:%s' % query)
```

try this and also try to debug your forms.py.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @pankaj-sharma it worked by running `python manage.py rebuild_index`! I'm now able to filter by tag but the things is that I can't call my tags in the search results like this:

```
 {% if  page_obj.object_list %}

  <ol class="row top20">

  {% for result in page_obj.object_list %}

   <div class="showcase col-sm-6 col-md-4">

           <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">
              <h3>{{result.object.title}}</h3>
              <img src="{{ result.object.image }}" class="img-responsive">
           </a>

<!-- I want to call it in the span below -->

          <div class="text-center">
          <span class="label label-info">{{result.object.ptags.name}}</span>
          </div>

    </div>
  {% endfor %}
 </ol>
</div>
```